# Making JRadioButton random

Tags: java, swing, random, jradiobutton

my data comes from query like this to my radio buttons:

```
radio1.setText(Question.get(i).getChoiceOne()) // assign ist choice to ist radio button
radio2.setText(Question.get(i).getChoiceTwo()) // assign second choice to second radio
radio3.setText(Question.get(i).getcorrectchoice()) // assign correct choice to third radio button
```

In this case each time the correct answer is assigned to third radio button which makes the quiz predictable.. Can I do it in some way where the correct choice some times assign to first radio, some times to second and so on?

Comment: @LukasRotter or simply `Collections.shuffle()` on that list.

Comment: @Selim Wow... Can't believe I never heard of that method before, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could do following:

```
String one = Question.get(i).getChoiceOne();
String two = Question.get(i).getChoiceTwo();
String three = Question.get(i).getcorrectchoice();

// construct list from questions.
List<String> choices = Arrays.asList(one, two, three);

// give random order to list
Collections.shuffle(choices);

// set radio button texts
radio1.setText(choices.get(0));
radio2.setText(choices.get(1));
radio3.setText(choices.get(2));
```

Comment: @Seleim thanks a lot. But suppose I want to calculate points then how can I figure out the correctchoice?

Comment: `if (Question.get(i).getcorrectchoice().equals(actionEvent.getSource().getText())) {...}`

Answer (score 0):

```
      int i = (Math.random() * 1000)%3;// generate a values between 0-2
      String[] answers = new String[3];
      answers[i] = Question.get(i).getcorrectchoice();// i is the index of right answer

      // insert the 2 other answers, what ever i you chose (i+1)%3 will put them in the remaining 2 places  
      answer[(i+1)%3] = Question.get(i).getfirstchoice(); 
      answer[(i+1)%3] = Question.get(i).getsecondchoice();
      i = (i+1)%3;// the original value of i
      // insert radios
      radio1.setText(answers[0]);
      radio2.setText(answers[1]);
      radio3.setText(answers[2]);

      //  get the right answer; get the text of the selected radio 
      if(textOfselectedRadio.quals(answers[i])){
      // correct 
      }
```

Comment: @Whynot thanks but I already used the Collections.shuffle(choices); method and it works. Now here I do not know how to point out correct answer and increment the score because the answer can be in one of the three radio buttons?      radio1.setText(choices.get(0));
radio2.setText(choices.get(1));
radio3.setText(choices.get(2));

Comment: you shold read and understand the code, all you are talking about is either in my code or in Selim's. for the score declare a static variable that should contain it; each time you get a right answer score is incremented. and finally if one of the answers resolved your problem don't forget to validate it =]

Comment: I know that a variable should be incremented if correct choice selected but my question is how to figure out the correct option in this code?    String one = Question.get(i).getChoiceOne();
String two = Question.get(i).getChoiceTwo();
String three = Question.get(i).getCorrectChoice();
List<String> choices = Arrays.asList(one, two, three);
Collections.shuffle(choices);
c1.setText(choices.get(0).toString());
c2.setText(choices.get(1).toString());
c3.setText(choices.get(2).toString());